# Cant Figure out how to Remove characters from Sting in PHP

Tags: php, string

I made Cron job using amazon affiliate api and getting price for perrticular product but its not what i want. Its probably super easy but i am new to coding and cant fegure it out

responce from amazon api is **INR 1,895.00** and i need **1895** as final result

```
    $price = "INR 1,895.00";

    $price = substr($price,4,10);

    //removes "INR "

    echo $price = (int)$price;

   // converts to integer
```

The value of $price i get 1 due to "," and i m not able to solve it

Comment: `str_replace()` try this, yes converting into int will return 1

Comment: [`sscanf`](http://php.net/sscanf) perhaps, or a regex replacing `/[^\d.]+/`.

Comment: why u want to convert into int??

Comment: This is a currency string - so you're probably better off looking at [NumberFormatter::parseCurrency](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parsecurrency.php)

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a built in filter to support this sort of thing

```
$price = "INR 1,895.00";
$price=( (float) filter_var( $price, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION ) ); //outputs 1895
```

This solution also supports values like 'INR 19.95', resulting in '19.95'

Comment: This *may* go wonky with other national currency formats where the point and comma are reversed, e.g. `EUR 1.895,00` in NL

Comment: @CD001 True, however, in this case data comes out of amazon api, which always has the same notation.